# au filetype mapping is not working

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

When I am doing

```
inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
```

it is working perfectly.

But, what I actually want is:

```
inoremap "" ""<++><esc>4hi
au FileType *.tex inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
```

Now, with this setting, in foo.tex, I am still getting the inoremap, not the ``""  for the tex file.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The `pat` for the `FileType` autocommand event should be a file *type*, not a file *name*. Try this instead:

```
au FileType tex inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
```